My 4 year old daughter does not know im her dad and her mom refuses to tell her
I will try to be as neutral as possible with the situation, my significant other, and I had a daughter and during the first two years of her life, I was experiencing mental health issues and homelessness, and was absent from her life.
Me and my significant other ended up getting back together, and we slowly started introducing our daughter to me as she has never really been around a man before. She didn’t want to tell her at first that I was her dad because it didn’t want to and these are her words freak her out all the sudden she has a dad. So for a whole entire year, I kind of sat back and just let the relationship with my daughter be fluid and grow on her and become close with her so I can eventually tell her that I’m her dad, but mom has been so against it.
We fell in a rough spot and I ended up losing my job and mom lost her job and we lost our apartment so our daughter moved in with her grandmother, my significant other rented a room from a family member that wouldn’t allow me to be there so now my daughter is at her grandmas and I haven’t seen her or talk to her in seven months. My significant other ended up losing her job and then she had to move in with me in the room that I’m renting, but she still will not let me see our daughter. She will not let me talk to her on the phone.
They don’t bring me up in conversation  or acknowledge that I’m asking about her every day trying to see her buying her gifts. I’m paying her daycare. I am financially supporting my daughter, but I do not get to see her and she still has no idea that I’m her father.
I have a full-time job, mentally healthy and I am providing as those were the requirements for me to be in my daughters life, but they are still not letting me see her. They will not tell her that I am her biological father. They do not tell her what her last name is she goes by her grandmother‘s last name which is not on her birth certificate it’s my last name, I’m just a total loss. I honestly wanna go behind my significant others back and just go to court. idk what to do please help.

You probably have a legal right to see her (depending on your country, etc.) so get some kind of legal help and go to court. This should define your rights in the future, not the whims of your SO. Don't do this behind her back; let her know that this is a last resort.

Mikey, welcome! Tough situation indeed and we feel your struggles. However, for a good question here, we need a clear question - and we can’t offer legal advice. You may want to check out [ask], then [edit] your question to make it clearer.

I don't believe this is a parenting question. If you want to approach your SO/ex and talk it out, that's an interpersonal problem (better posted at Interpersonal.SE), and if you want to bypass your SO/ex it's a legal problem (best to simply consult a lawyer directly).

I'm going to start by summarising what others have already said in the comments:

Find out what your legal rights are. The best way is to talk to a lawyer, but I recognise that might be difficult. Depending on where you are there may be free legal resources available, or web pages you can read.

Armed with that knowledge, go talk to your SO about access. Don't lead with the legal stuff, but knowing what your rights are will let you be clear about what you can reasonably expect.


Your daughter has a right to know who you are, and the sooner she learns the less the shock will be. Your SO is storing up trouble by hiding this. Your daughter is going to find out sooner or later, and if it is later she is likely to be angry that she wasn't told earlier.
When you discuss this with your SO, frame the entire conversation about what is best for your daughter. Its her right to know. She has a right to contact with her father. She will be hurt and angry if she finds out who you are later, especially if she gets told by someone else, or sees her birth certificate. She will blame your SO for this. Your SO can't hide you from her forever. Her legal name will be on her school records, so she's going to see it then.
